# Pycharm cannot complete object attributed that is coming from different file

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm

Here is an example:

```
# file1
from file2 import *

class test:
    def __init__(self):
         self.test = 5

    def send_args(self):
        test2(self)
```

```
# file2
def test2(self):
    print(self.test)
```

It seems like Pycharm does not know how to autocomplete the self.test.
Visual Studio Code is doing this out of the box.

I tried everything.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mentioned that the self is being sent to the function in file2 by file1.

Comment: I added the new code below.
Its still does not work.

Comment: Dupe: [Python seeing function parameters as class for autocompletion](//stackoverflow.com/q/51467024)